# Merge two files by line numbers using awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two files, say FileA and FileB. FileA has n lines and FileB has 5n lines. I want to merge these two files into a new file FileC such that every 5th line in FileB is replaced by a line from FileA.

### Example

FileA :
0\n, 1\n

FileB:
A\n B\n C\n D\n E\n F\n G\n H\n I\n J\n

FileC:
0\n B\n C\n D\n E\n 1\n G\n H\n I\n J\n

(\n is newline)

I know how to do this using a loop in shell but I was hoping to learn a cleaner way of doing this using perhaps awk or sed. I found many solutions of processing two files using awk but they are mostly based on field comparisons and not line numbers. I apologize if this question is a repeat, if so, please point me to a similar question with answers.

Comment: Why does this question have a downvote? If downvoters drop a comment about how the question can be improved only then it is constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{if(NR%5==1) { getline line < "FILEA"; print line; } else { print $0; }}' FILEB
```

If you want to use filenames as arguments you can also try this:

```
awk 'NR!=FNR{exit} {if(NR%5==1) { getline line < ARGV[2]; print line; } else { print $0; }}' FILEB FILEA
```

Comment: Test this on a couple of sample files. It doesn't work.

Comment: Updated it.. It was an accidental submit. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR!=FNR{exit}NR%5==1{getline <ARGV[2]}{print}' FileB FileA
```

Note that filenames are entered in the opposite order: largefile smallfile.

This also gracefully handles the case that FileA is shorter than 1/5th FileB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't work. It prints 0 a b c d e 1 f g h i j , instead of 0 b c d e 1 g h i j. It adds a line to file B instead of replacing

Comment: Updated to do replace instead of insert.